DFT warn: LUMO = HOMO
I'm trying to do DFT calculations at gamma point of carbon atoms with periodic boundary conditions and atomic orbital basis using the package pyscf.
I have noticed that pyscf outputs a warning that the LUMO-HOMO gap is zero, i.e. that LUMO = HOMO for some of the configurations. In these cases the calculation doesn't converge. Can you explain why it's a problem to calculate states (i.e. why scf doesn't converge) when the LUMO-HOMO gap is zero using pyscf DFT? If this is a general issue for DFT and not particular for pyscf, please let us know.

SCF calculations for systems with zero or small HOMO-LUMO gap (such as metals) can exhibit very slow convergence or may even fail to converge. This problem arises because the energetic ordering of orbitals and states can switch during the SCF optimization leading to discontinuities in the optimization. Using fractional MO occupation numbers can improve the convergence for small-gap systems. In this approach, the occupation numbers of MOs around the Fermi level are allowed to assume non-integer values. This "occupation smearing" allows one to include multiple electron configurations in the same optimization, which improves the stability of the optimization (reference).
You said you are studying carbon. This happens with diamond if you study bulk with a vacancy (one atom removed). In that case the HOMO-LUMO gap is zero even though it is not a metal. I downloaded an example from pyscf and had a go:
from pyscf.pbc import gto, scf, dft
import numpy

cell = gto.Cell()
cell.a = '''
3.5668  0       0
0       3.5668  0
0       0       3.5668'''
cell.atom = '''C     0.      0.      0.    
              C     0.8917  0.8917  0.8917
              C     1.7834  1.7834  0.    
              C     2.6751  2.6751  0.8917
              C     2.6751  0.8917  2.6751
              C     0.      1.7834  1.7834
              C     0.8917  2.6751  2.6751'''
cell.basis = 'gth-szv'
cell.pseudo = 'gth-pade'
cell.verbose = 4
cell.build()

mf = dft.RKS(cell)
#mf = scf.addons.smearing_(mf, sigma=.1, method='fermi')
mf.xc = 'LDA,VWN'
edft = mf.kernel()
print("DFT energy (per unit cell) = %.17g" % edft)

After observing that the warning you cite appears (WARN: HOMO 0.4990283 == LUMO 0.4990283) and the optimization fails; try to uncomment the line that reads mf = scf.addons.smearing_(mf, sigma=.1, method='fermi') and run the script again. You will see that now it converges just fine. Smearing sets fractional occupancies according to a temperature function.

HOMO (highest occupied molecular orbital) and LUMO (lowest unoccupied molecular orbital) are only defined for molecular systems. For a periodic system, the gap being equal to zero just indicates that the system is metallic.
If your system doesn't have a metallic behavior, then, yes, obtaining a zero gap is a problem of the input (pseudopotentials, functionals, basis sets, etc.) or even the code you're using (in this case pyscf) and doesn't have to do with DFT.

I think what the OP is asking is why the following web page reads «A level shift increases the gap between the occupied and virtual orbitals, thereby slowing down and stabilizing the orbital update», or «Fractional occupations can also be invoked to help the SCF converge for small gap systems»: https://pyscf.org/user/scf.html#converging-scf-iterations
It sounds there is an issue with small LUMO-HOMO gap since the authors of that page makes it sound like it should be 'obvious' what it is. If that's correct, it would be nice to know what the issue is

From what part of the post did you infer all that stuff?

I read the question and searched google
